# Postgres: copy one remote DB to another

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to copy a database from one remote server to another one. I've tried several different commands from my terminal (macOS):

- "pg_dump -U postgres -d [DB] -f [DB].sql"
- "pg_dump -U postgres -d [DB] -h [Host] -f [DB].sql"

But nothing works. I get errors like "pg_dump: error: connection to database [DB] failed: FATAL:  database [DB] does not exist".

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I've tried to edit the pg_hba.conf, but it didn't work as well..

Comment: Are you actually using the value `[DB]` or is that a placeholder? In any case the error is straight forward the database you are trying to dump does not exist in the Postgres cluster you are pointing at.

Comment: The words in [] are placeholders. I'm using my credentials. I can access the named [DB] in psql with these credentials (password etc. included). And yes, if I type "psql -l" to list all the databases, I can't see the one we're talking about. So is pg_dump the right method to copy a remote DB? Or how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to make this work is :

1. First sub-option below  outputs plain text file, second custom format(binary) file

   a) `pg_dump -C -h host_name -U user_name -d database_name -f database.sql`

   `-C` tells pg_dump to provide the command to create the  database
   on restore.

   b) `pg_dump -Fc  -h host_name -U user_name -d database_name-f database.out`
2. To restore you need different programs

   a) For plain text option 1a do:

   `psql -d postgres -h host_name -U user_name  -f database.sql`

   You need to connect to existing database, postgres in this case,
   and then the commands from `-C` above will create
   the database(database_name) and then connect to it for rest of operation.

   b) For custom format option 1b:

   `pg_restore -C -d postgres -h host_name -U user_name database.out`

   **Note**: just specify the dump file(database.out) do not use `-f`.

More options and details can be found:

[pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

and

[pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

Look in the **Notes** section at the bottom of link for examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I think my problem is somewhere else: In order to allow connections to a remote server, I need to make adjustments in my pg_hba.config and postgresql.config files. For the first one, I need an IP Mask, but unfortunately, this is not provided by my host (IP changes dynamically). So from what I understand it won't be possible to copy the database with the above commands from the named host. Am I right?

Comment: I doubt it. Look at the log for the remote Postgres server, I'm betting you will see something like `FATAL:  database [DB] does not exist`. To confirm try a `psql` connection to the `postgres` database on the server. If it where a `pg_hba.conf` error you would get a different message.

Comment: A `pg_hba.conf` error would be along lines of: `pg_dump: error: connection to database "test" failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry...`